# referencing a model that hasn't been created, avoid the error: relation "TABLENAME" does not exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am very new to sequelize and postgresql. I looked a lot for an answer to this issue but I couldn't find anything related to my it. If this question is has an answer in another post I apologize for repeating and I'll gladly refer to the other post and remove my post from here.

At the beginning I did:

```
sequelize model:generate --name user --attributes username:string,email:string,password:string,collection_id:INTEGER
```

where collection_id references another table ID. I did the same for the collection table:

```
sequelize model:generate --name collection --attributes plant_id:integer,user_id:integer
```

in my models I updated the association
in the collection model I added:

```
models.collection.belongsTo(models.user, {foreignKey: 'user_id'})
```

and in the user model I added:

```
models.user.hasOne(models.collection, {foreignKey: 'collection_id'})
```

And in the migration files I added:

```
user_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: {
            tableName: 'user'
          }
        }
  }

collection_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: {
            tableName: 'collection'
          }
        }
      }
```

in their respective files. Now the issue here is that sequelize is trying to migrate the user model before the collection model, however the later is referenced in the first model and I am getting this error "relation "collection" does not exist" which only makes sense. Now if I removed the reference, is there a way to add it later after I migrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reference` sets a foreign key on the table under the hood. But you can't have 2 tables with foreign keys pointing to each other (circular reference).

You set a foreign key on the "child" table which points to the "parent" table. In your case, if `collection` belongs to `user` then `collection` is "child".

You can read this [paragraph from Sequalize docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html#difference-between-hasone-and-belongsto) with some details about the difference between `hasOne` and `belongsTo` (and read about those associations in Sequalize separately as well). `{foreignKey: 'collection_id'}` which you pass to `hasOne` method is actually supposed to be in `collections` table (**target** model), means in your case it doesn't make sense and should be like this instead:

```js
models.user.hasOne(models.collection, {foreignKey: 'user_id'})
```

So, you don't need `collection_id` column in your `user` table, can safely remove it.

Comment: I removed the references from the user table and that solved the issue. They're now only linked through the user_id in the collection table. Thank you.